# How to set snapping hotkeys in blender 2.8

Tags: shortcut, snapping

I am trying to set up a few custom hotkeys for ease of access. I want to set up v to be point snap and x to be grid snap. So far if I hover to the snapping menu and try to bind the hotkey there it hotkeys the menu. I did a bit of digging around and found out that I can use the following way. Except when I try it in this new version of blender I get some errors. Just wondering if anyone can tell me the proper way to access these commands without having to make an operator for it.

[image: vertex snapping]